# JOI to validate that selling quantity less than buying quantity

Tags: node.js, mongoose, joi

I have two mongoose schema for trading app, one is buySchema

```
const buySchema = new Schema({
    parentId: String,
    buyingPrice: {
        type: Number,
        min: [0, 'Price can\'t be negative']
    },
    sharesBought: {
        type: Number,
        min: [0, 'No. of Shares can\'t be negative']
    },
    day: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    sells: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Sell'
    }],
})
```

and other is sellSchema

```
const sellSchema = new Schema({
    sellingPrice:Number,
    sharesSold:Number,
    day: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})
```

Now I want to make sure that **sharesSold** is never greater than **sharesBought**.

```
module.exports.sellSchema = Joi.object({
    sell: Joi.object({
        sellingPrice: Joi.number().min(0).required(),
        sharesSold: Joi.number().min(0).max(***'How to handle this part'***).required(),
        day: Joi.date().required()
    }).required()
})
```

I don't know how to write JOI schema condition such that max value for sharesSold is less than sharesBought? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you can validate with joi. Your joi schema is only accepting information about sold shares, it doesn't have access to user's already existing shares. For better security and consistency it needs to be done on the application logic where there is access to stored `boughtShares` information